# How to catch all exceptions in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I was wondering if there is a way to catch all the exceptions that are thrown in a laravel app and store them in database ?

I have been looking at some packages but coudn't find anything that tells where and how to catch the exceptions.

Answer (score 14):

for catch all errors and log them you need to edit `App\Exceptions\Handler` file like this

```
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception){
        // log the error
        return response()->json([
            'status' => $exception->getStatusCode(),
            'error' => $exception->getMessage()
        ]);
   }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#the-exception-handler),
You need to customize the `render()` method of `App\Exceptions\Handler`.

Edit the *app/Exceptions/Handler.php*:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $error =$e->getMessage();

    //do your stuff with the error message 

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```