# How to i handle Laravel error if script fails InvalidArgumentException: View [welcome] not found

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-9, laravel-api

When my script fails in a Laravel 9 app, instead of it to outputing the JSON I configured, it shows this:

> InvalidArgumentException: View [welcome] not found. in file C:\Users\kgl\Documents\biomandate\secure\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder.php on line 137

I think I need to adjust the `App\Exceptions` handler but somehow I still have error. Please how do I fix this?

For example: if the below code fails, I need the response to be something I have configured.

```php
$user = new User();
$user->name = $validatedData['name'];
$user->email = $validatedData['email'];
$user->password = Hash::make($validatedData['password']);
$user->token = $token;
$user->save()
```

Comment: The error is telling you that a view called 'Welcome' was not found. Do you expect this view to exist? Do you know anything about this view?

Comment: No i do not need that view i just want to return my own response if it fails. how do i disable Laravel's default exception handling from taking over.

Comment: Let me ask it slightly differently then. Would you like to remove the reference to the Welcome view? It's unclear to me at this point whether your question seeks to get through an error, or whether you want to implement a custom error handler.

Comment: There are soooo many ways to answer your question, but 'view not found' is actually the wrong question. Without answering your question, go to Exceptions/Handler.php, there's a `render` function. Loop through possible variations of the Exception,      InvalidArgumentException is one of them. Let's say you do a `match` on the Exception. If it's that InvalidArgumentException then handle it by .... showing a 404 not found page?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes i want to implement a custom error handler so that when save() is not successful let me return a clearer error

Comment: @UnderDog can you tell me how. content of the render function

Comment: Then maybe this answer will be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536365/how-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-laravel